# Converting long table into sas table in SAS

Tags: sas, transpose

I am trying to convert a long table into wide table in SAS. I have the following data

```
Team ID Player  Score
1        Andy   12
2       Andy    32
1       Andy    2
3       Andy    0
1       Andy    43
3         Bin   33
1        Bin    23
3        Bin    34
3         Bin   3
1         Bin   12
2        Ray    34
3        Ray    52
2        Ray    11
```

Now I want to add score of each player teamwise like

```
Team ID Player  Score
1       Andy    46
1       Ray     34
1       Bin     33
2       Andy    43
2        Ray    52
3         Bin   72
3         Ray   11
```

Now I want to tanspose the players so that I get one row for each team like this.

```
Team ID Andy    Ray Bin
1        46     34  33
2        43     52  .
3          .    11  72
```

I tried with proc transpose and proc means but couldn't find a suitable solution. Will appreciate your help for a sas code.

Regards

Comment: I don't know what has happened to my tables!

Comment: Hi you might want to fix that formatting to aid readability. Also, could you share what code you've tried so far?

Comment: Can you explain how Andy gets a score of 46 in the second table?

Comment: sorry for not posting correct values in table 2 @Robert Penridge my apologies for the incorrect value for Andy, It should be sum of all values of Andy in each team seperately. Anyhow as I had a very very large table what I did in the end is used prom means to sum scores using class statement and then transposing it. Thanks for the ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work. First sort your data by "Team":

```
Proc SORT Data=Have Out=Want1;
by Team;
Run;
```

Then Transpose your data as your variable will be sorted "By Team" (vertical) with "Id Player" (horizontal):

```
PROC TRANSPOSE Data=Want1 Out=Want2 let;
Id Player;
By Team;
Var Score;
Run;
```